# API won't authenticate against AAD with token passed from SPA using MSAL

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to adapt the sample B2C code referenced [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/) and [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/blob/master/index.js) to work against our organizations AAD.

I have a SPA app that is successfully authenticating with AAD via MSAL and receiving a token.  The SPA app can use the token to pull data from the MS Graph API -- so I'm certain the token is valid.

The SPA is currently running locally @ localhost:9000.

I have a second app that is a Nodejs API running @ localhost:3000.  The SPA app makes a call to the API passing the same token used for the GraphAPI.  The API app is supposed to use that token to authenticate the user and provide access to the API; however, I only ever get back a 401 - Unauthorized.

(I'm using Aurelia for my client side code.  HTTP request is made using Aurelia's HTTP client).

Here is the SPA code used to call the API:

```
//Not entirely sure what to use as the scope here!!  API is registered to allow user.read Graph API scope.
this.config.msClient.acquireTokenSilent(["user.read"]).then(token => {
   console.log("Token acquired silently.");
   this.makeAPICall(token);
}, error => { ... }
);

makeAPICall(token) {
   this.http.configure(config => {
     config
       .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:3000/')
       .withDefaults({
           headers: {
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
           }
      }

      this.http.fetch("user/0")
       .then(response => {
          debugger;  //response is 401 Unauthenticated at this point
       }, error => { ... });

}
```

I've registered an Application at apps.dev.microsoft.com for my API.  And here is my server side (API) Nodejs code:

```
const express = require("express")
const port = 3000
const passport = require("passport")
var BearerStrategy = require("passport-azure-ad").BearerStrategy;

var userList = [
    {id: 1, first: "Mickey", last: "Mouse", age: 95},
    {id: 2, first: "Donald", last: "Duck", age: 85},
    {id: 3, first: "Pluto", last: "leDog", age: 70}
]

var options = {
    identityMetadata: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    clientID: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",  //My registered App Id
    passReqToCallback: false,
    validateIssuer: true,
    issuer: "xxxxxxx"  //Our tenant name
};

var strategy = new BearerStrategy(options, (token, done) => {
    console.log(token);
    done(null,{}, {scope: '*'});
})


const app = express()
app.use(passport.initialize())
passport.use(strategy);

//Allow CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Accept");
    next();
})

app.get("/",(request, response) => {  //Unauthenticated -- always works
    response.send("Hello World!")
})

app.get("/user/:id",passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer',{session: false }),
  (request, response) => {
    //Never seem to get here (when debugging) as authenticate always fails
    let id = request.params["id"];
    let user = userList[id];
    if(user) response.json(user);
    else response.send("No user found")
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port)
})
```

I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding how this all works but would appreciate some guidance as to what I need to change to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokens are like bank checks: they can only be cached by the person they were written for. A token issued for the MS Graph will have as audience the Microsoft Graph, and should be accepted by the Microsoft Graph only. Any other API X receiving that token should refuse it. A client intending to invoke X should request a token for X, regardless of whether it already has a token for another service (like the Microsoft graph). Here there's an example of that flow, implemented with ADAL JS: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/ 
At this point Azure AD v2 (used by MSAL) is not capable of issues access tokens for custom API: the feature is being worked on, but we have no ETA for when it will become available in production. Until then, this topology isn't supported with v2 (hence MSAL JS). Sorry!

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, MSAL only provides access tokens for the Graph API?

Comment: As of today, that's the case. The v2 endpoint issues access tokens for the Microsoft Graph and id_tokens for app sign in.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.  This has helped a lot.

Comment: One more question, can you help me understand what's going on.  This link https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-nodejs-webapi-v2 seems to indicate that they are securing a custom Node API with AD v2.  (Granted they're not using MSAL)  I understood you to say this wasn't possible.  What am I missing?

Comment: that sample cannot actually work without the access token feature discussed here- thanks for the headsup! I contacted the authors of the sample, we'll adjust language (or pull until we have the service side feature) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  I was going nuts trying to figure out what the difference was and why my code wasn't working.

Comment: Just curious what you recommend at this point for developing a SPA app in javascript/html that needs to use OIDC against the Azure AD?  It seems as though the current OIDC implementation in Azure does not work with most javascript client libraries that I'm finding (oidc-client-js for example).  ADAL (from what I'm reading uses oAuth 2 and not OIDC).   Maybe I'm just not reading the right stuff?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The issue discussed here is that Azure ad v2 doesn't issue access tokens for custom API, it's not a matter of what libraries are used. I am also not following the distinction between oauth2 and oidc here- in js you use the implicit flow as defined by oauth, and we pass extra parameters as defined by oidc. That's both oauth and oidc all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a newb to oAuth/OIDC, etc. so I may not be entirely clear in my questions.  Point taken in regards to oAuth and OIDC -- using OIDC inherently implies the use of oAuth.  My question stemmed from a desire to use OIDC from a SPA client to access both Microsoft Graph as well as my own API.  MSAL won't work so I'm left with (as far as I can find) ADAL and oidc-client-js for client-side oidc libraries.  But, my understanding is that AD v1 used resources instead of scopes which aren't supported by oidc-client-js.  So is ADAL my only solution at this point?

Comment: If you want to write a SPA that uses Azure AD v1, call Graph and call your own API you can use ADAL JS. Samples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi for angular.

Answer (score 0):

A year later and it is now possible to secure your custom API with MSAL.  In the app portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) you can create your app, then "add a platform" twice - once for your web app SPA, and another for your web api.  In the web api, create a "scope" e.g. "api://e892d79e-03e7-4e5e-.../access_as_user", and then pass this scope into the acquireTokenSilent call (instead of "user.read" in the example above).